# Application/tool to upload, manage and download software releases?

Tags: release-management

I am looking for a web based software management application to which our developers can upload releases of our software along with release notes etc, and then our QA/support teams can browse and download the different applications and versions (preferably with a status or workflow to indicate that its passed QA), almost like an internal software store/market place.

This would need support all sorts of file and application types for different platforms.

Unfortunalty my googling skills have failed me here, not sure if im using the right terms. I keep coming up with things for specific platforms like iOS or Windows market place, or package repos.

Im hoping there is an off the shelf solution that would suit our needs.